# using scanf in C; are both %i and %d the same in the matter of being signed or unsigned?

Tags: c, scanf, unsigned, signed

In many websites (like:[GeeksForGeeks: Difference between %d and %i format specifier in C language](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-d-format-specifier-c-language/) or [TutorialsPoint: Difference between %d and %i format specifier in C](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/difference-between-d-and-i-format-specifier-in-c)) they say:
in `scanf`;
`%d` takes integer value as signed decimal integer and
`%i` takes integer value as integer value with decimal, hexadecimal or octal type.

Using the word "signed" only for `%d` and not for `%i`
I expected `%i` to accept unsigned values only
but
`%i` works perfectly fine with negative numbers.
So what is it about `%i` that no one mentions the word "signed" for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Using the word "signed" only for %d and not for %i I expected %i to
> accept unsigned values only but %i works perfectly fine with negative
> numbers. So what is it about %i that no one mentions the word "signed"
> for it?

I wouldn't say "no one".  The language standard says for `%d`:

> Matches an optionally signed decimal integer. [...] The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.

and for `%i`:

> Matches an optionally signed integer. [...] The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to signed integer.

The language around signedness of the input representation and of the target of the corresponding pointer argument is identical for the two.

I can only speculate about why any web page author describes the meaning of `%i` with less clarity and precision than you would like or than the standard does.  Perhaps some are confused by the fact that `%x` for hexadecimal format requires a pointer to an unsigned integer.  Perhaps some are sloppy.  Perhaps some lazily rely on the imprecise language of other web pages instead of on a primary source.

Comment: From the standard there is a subtle difference. `i` can match integer in any format (such as prefixed with `0x` while `%d` only matching decimals

Comment: Yes, @EugeneSh., the question already mentions that, so I saw no need to reiterate it in this answer.  Even so, the difference makes a small impact on the bits I quoted: `%d` matches "an optionally signed *decimal* integer", whereas `%i` matches "an optionally signed integer".

Comment: Indeed. Missed that part of the question

Answer (score 2):

"integer value as integer value with decimal, hexadecimal or octal type."   --> No, not *type*, but with decimal, octal or hexadecimal text prefix.

The matching type for `"%i"` is still a pointer to `int`.

It allows "0x123" whereas `"%d"` only sees that a 0 and stops at `x`.